# Is there a way to remove/ignore matches that have a low score in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting results that have scores of over 40 for a search but I am also getting way more items with scores under 5.  Is there a way to set a bottom threshold so I am not displaying these low-score results but only the high scoring ones?  Or is there a better way of doing this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/min-score.html) option in Search API.

Hope this helps.